# How to create your own data-frame?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 dataframes (`df1, df2 and df3`) which are being imported to 3 MySQL tables every-time I run the code. Now I'm trying to make a new data-frame which is 'monitoring' those 3 data-frames (or tables).

**My expected outcome:**

```
   df   -   time_run   -   count_rows   - count_columns 
0  df1  -   12:00:23   -   100          -  9
1  df2  -   12:00:24   -   1500         -  8 
2  df3  -   12:00:26   -   190          -  6
```

`df` shows the name of the dataframe. `time_run` stands for the time (in HMS) the dataframe was exported to MySQL, `count_rows` stands for the amount of rows exported to MySQL and `count_columns` has to be the amount of columns exported to MySQL.

**This is my code until now...:**

```
#This is the last part of the code which sends the df's to MySQL.
df1.to_sql('table_df1', con = engine, if_exists = 'replace')
df2.to_sql('table_df2', con = engine, if_exists = 'replace')
df3.to_sql('table_df3', con = engine, if_exists = 'replace')

list_df = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']

df_df = pd.DataFrame(list_df)
df_time_run =
df_count_rows = 
df_count_columns = 
    
the_dataframe = df_df.join([df_time_run, df_count_rows,df_count_columns])
```

My aim was to make 4 data-frames (`df_df, df_time_run, df_count_rows` and `df_count_columns`) and join them together to 1 data-frame (`the_dataframe`). However, I only managed to make `df_df` and I got stuck after that...

Answer (score 0):

Try this......

```
list_df = [df1, df2, df3]
for i in list_df:
    df_df.append(i)
the_dataframe=df_df
```

Comment: How about df_time_run, df_count_rows and df_count_columns?

Comment: This is to merge 4 dataframes i could not get what is  df_time_run, df_count_rows and df_count_columns

Comment: oke. But I already know how to merge. thank you though.